# Write to nth line of terminal without rewriting everything else

Tags: shell-script, terminal

In my bash script, I'd like to have a ticking clock on the first line of the screen and have other text below it, but I don't want to write the text to the screen every time the clock ticks.  In other words, I have this:

```
15:00:25 Tue Aug 30 2016
The quick brown fox 
jumps over the lazy dog
```

I want the first line to change every second without rewriting the last two lines.

Comment: do you need to do something else at the same time, or do you _just_ want the clock?

Comment: Um, maybe I don't understand your question, but I think I just want the clock. What kind of "something else" are you thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various [terminal tricks](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) are possible, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

emitdate() {
  tput sc
  tput cup 0 0
  date
  tput rc
}

clear
echo
echo tqbf
echo jotld

while :; do
  emitdate
  sleep 1
done
```